# Reference html modal comes empty when try to execute from other component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an HTML component with a modal as:

```
<ng-template #modalContent let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Inactivity alert</h4>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn-close"
      aria-label="Close"
      (click)="modal.close()"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Your session is about to expire! You will be logged out in
    {{ countdown }} seconds.
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close()">
      Remain logged in
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline-dark"
      (click)="modal.close('LogOut')">
      Log out
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The component of this modal is the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-timeout',
  templateUrl: './timeout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeout.component.scss']
})
export class TimeoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent!: ElementRef;
  countdown?: number = undefined;
  closeResult = '';

  public destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    public idle: Idle,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    public authService: AuthService,
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated) return;

    idle.setIdle(10); // 14 minutes
    idle.setTimeout(60); // 1 minute
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    idle.setAutoResume(AutoResume.notIdle);

    // do something when the user becomes idle
    idle.onIdleStart.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(() => {
      this.open(this.modalContent);
    });

    // do something when the user times out
    idle.onTimeout.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(() => {
      this.logout(true);
    });

    // countdown
    idle.onTimeoutWarning
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(seconds => (this.countdown = seconds));
  }

  //#region Lifecycle Hooks
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reset();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region Public Methods
  reset(): void {
    this.idle.watch();
    this.countdown = undefined;
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }

  open(content: ElementRef<any>): void {
    this.modalService
      .open(content, {
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
      })
      .result.then(result => {
        if (result === 'LogOut') {
          this.logout();
        } else {
          this.reset();
        }
      });
  }

  logout(setTimedout = false): void {
    this.authService.logout();
    if (setTimedout) localStorage.setItem('timedOut', '1');
  }

  //#endregion
}
```

And I want to run this component when my user logs in, so in my Login component I have this:

```
onSubmit(): void {
   this.authService
    ...finalize(() => {
       this.timeoutComponent.reset();
          this.executeTimeoutCode();
    }
}

 executeTimeoutCode(): void {
    const timeoutComponent = new TimeoutComponent(
      this.idle,
      this.modalService,
      this.authService,
      this.cd
    );

    if (!timeoutComponent.authService.isAuthenticated) return;

    timeoutComponent.idle.setIdle(10); // 14 minutes
    timeoutComponent.idle.setTimeout(60); // 1 minute
    timeoutComponent.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    timeoutComponent.idle.setAutoResume(AutoResume.notIdle);

    timeoutComponent.idle.onIdleStart
      .pipe(takeUntil(timeoutComponent.destroy$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        timeoutComponent.open(timeoutComponent.modalContent);
      });

    timeoutComponent.idle.onTimeout
      .pipe(takeUntil(timeoutComponent.destroy$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        timeoutComponent.logout(true);
      });

    timeoutComponent.idle.onTimeoutWarning
      .pipe(takeUntil(timeoutComponent.destroy$))
      .subscribe(seconds => (timeoutComponent.countdown = seconds));

    timeoutComponent.idle.watch(); // Start the Idle instance
  }
```

When modal tries to open, it just comes as an empty modal. I think this is because when it sends parameters to the modal component from the login component, as I create a new instance of TimeoutComponent, it does not have an idea what is the modalContent parameter at this line:

```
 timeoutComponent.open(timeoutComponent.modalContent);
```

My question is, how can I reference the modal content of my HTML modal component when I create a new instance of the modal component?